# Array reclassification with numpy

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I have a large (50000 x 50000) 64-bit integer NumPy array containing 10-digit numbers.  There are about 250,000 unique numbers in the array.

I have a second reclassification table which maps each unique value from the first array to an integer between 1 and 100.  My hope would be to reclassify the values from the first array to the corresponding values in the second.

I've tried two methods of doing this, and while they work, they are quite slow. In both methods I create a blank (zeros) array of the same dimensions.

```
new_array = np.zeros(old_array.shape)
```

First method:

```
for old_value, new_value in lookup_array:
    new_array[old_array == old_value] = new_value
```

Second method, where lookup_array is in a pandas dataframe with the headings "Old" and "New:

```
for new_value, old_values in lookup_table.groupby("New"):
    new_array[np.in1d(old_array, old_values)] = new_value
```

Is there a faster way to reclassify values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Store the lookup table as a 250,000 element array where for each index you have the mapped value. For example, if you have something like:

```
lookups = [(old_value_1, new_value_1), (old_value_2, new_value_2), ...]
```

Then you can do:

```
idx, val = np.asarray(lookups).T
lookup_array = np.zeros(idx.max() + 1)
lookup_array[idx] = val
```

When you get that, you can get your transformed array simply as:

```
new_array = lookup_array[old_array]
```